# parse and order csv file in django template

Tags: python, django, csv

How to parse csv file into django template and sort them by:

**myfile.csv**

```
status, date, user, rating

Registered, 12-10-2016, user1, 8.75

Registered, 22-05-2016, user2, 9.23

Registered, 19-11-2016, user3, 7.00
```

Currently i'm trying to do things like this:

---

**Views.py**

```
args = {}
file_url = urllib2.Request("http://server.local:8000/static/myfile.csv", None, {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
file_url_response = urllib2.urlopen(file_url)
pre_reader = csv.reader(file_url_response)
args['list'] = pre_reader
return render_to_response('template.html', args)
```

---

**template.html**

```
{% for row in list %}
<p>
    {% for item in row %}
        {{ item }}
    {% endfor %}
</p>
{% endfor %}
```

---

Rendered HTML response is:

> status, date, user, rating
>
> Registered, 12-10-2016, user1, 8.75
>
> Registered, 22-05-2016, user2, 9.23
>
> Registered, 19-11-2016, user3, 7.00

---

But I want to do something like this:

```
<table>
{% for row in list %}
<tr>
    <td>
        {{ row.status }}
    </td>
    <td>
        {{ row.date }}
    </td>
    <td>
        {{ row.user }}
    </td>
    <td>
        {{ row.rating }}
    </td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
</table>
```

Also it would be great If I could order by values, so users can order results by date or by rating

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your view function do this.

```
...
csv_dict = {rows[0]:rows[1] for rows in pre_reader}
args['csv_dict'] = csv_dict
...
```

Then you will have a dict in your template that you can reorder using `regroup` tag. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/templates/builtins/#regroup

Comment: Can you extend your answer, with examples may be?

Comment: About regrouping?

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like {{row.0}}, see [Variables and lookups](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/templates/api/#variables-and-lookups), just change your template to
**template.html**:

```
<table>
{% for row in list %}
<tr>
    <td>
        {{ row.0 }}
    </td>
    <td>
        {{ row.1 }}
    </td>
    <td>
        {{ row.2 }}
    </td>
    <td>
        {{ row.3 }}
    </td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
</table>
```

Comment: Sorry, but it doesn't meet needs, because this way I have All values of nth column, not row (Don't know why it's so)